# how to keep stock in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am wondering how to keep track of the owners assets. I don't think having an asset called 'stock' would be very effective in this regard, because that would not seem like the blockchain way.

Let say you are sending a shipment with Product asset to another owner. This owner needs to accept the shipment of products. When he accepted it should I add these products to an inventory asset of that owner?

The other option is when the new owner accepted the shipment, do nothing. And when the owner wants to know his inventory he queries all the shipments with his signature to get the ID of the assets he owns.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you reading the official **Commercial Paper Tutorial** which is similar to what you're trying to do.

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/tutorial/commercial_paper.html#